# Show/Hide Editor not working in magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg

Show/Hide editor is not working in static blocks. I am getting following Errors in the console -

> Refused to execute script from
>   https://www.example.com/admin/cms/block/edit/block_id/20/key/f3ee116b456375338c3747b3ab97692ba62457613c332ab989c7d8431ce2841f//plugins/style/editor_plugin.js
>
> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it! The issue was due to minification of js files. After disabling the minification, the wysiwyg editor started working again.

Got a bit of idea from this - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11577